# Adding a HyperLink column to a GridView from a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datatable

I got this:

```
public partial class VerAgenda : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        if (!IsPostBack)
        {


            List<Funcion> fun = Festival.Instancia.ListaFunciones;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();



            if (fun.Count() == 0)
                mensaje.InnerText = "No hay funciones disponibles";

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Espectaculo", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fecha", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hora", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sala", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Detalles", typeof(string)));

            foreach (Funcion f in fun)
            {
                string pais = "";
                while (pais == "")
                {
                    List<Espectaculo> esp = Festival.Instancia.ListaEspectaculos;
                    int es = 0;
                    while (es < esp.Count() && pais == "")
                    {
                        if (esp[es].Nombre == f.Espectaculo)
                            pais = esp[es].Pais;
                        es++;
                    }
                }
                string link = "test";
                dt.Rows.Add(f.Espectaculo, f.Fecha, f.HoraIni, pais, link);
                tblAgenda.DataSource = dt;
                tblAgenda.DataBind();
                this.tblAgenda.Visible = true;                


        }

    }

}
```

}

For this markup:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="tblAgenda" runat="server">
   </asp:GridView>
```

Fancy, I know. I need to know how to add an URL to each row, formatting it from details on the list (ie: "/xxx.aspx?funcion" + fun.IndexOf[f] + ".aspx" or something like that. I think that would be an HyperLinkColumn or something, but I can't seem to make it work.

The idea would be to populate the GridView server-side... It works fine for the strings right now.

I realize this is a most newbie question, but I would really appreciate some help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add columns to your `GridView` and use [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield(v=vs.110).aspx) something like this:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblAgenda" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField = "Name" />
         <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Name" DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/xyz.aspx?Id={0}" HeaderText="Name"/>
        ----Other columns
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Edit:**

Bind it using DataTable something like this:-

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name") });
dt.Rows.Add(1, "Pam);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Richard");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Mary");
tblAgenda.DataSource = dt;
tblAgenda.DataBind();
```

Comment: Cool, thanks... but how do I get the DataNavigateUrlFormatString to take from a variable? This is not from a DB, just a datatable... I mean, from the C# code?

Comment: Ok... so I got a link. But I still don't get how to pass the variable to the field... I mean, the NavigateUrl part, can't get that to work now...

Comment: @dumber_than_thou - No, don't include those attributes, i thought you are binding directly, only put `NavigateUrl` attribute in HyperLinkField and I have used `Id` there instead use whatever column you want to bind from your DataTable.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how the whole tag should look now? I'm getting a server message saying that this should have a data binding...

Comment: @dumber_than_thou - Please check code behind and Mark-Up update.

Comment: Amazing! Got it now. Thank you so much. Can't upvote for lack of rep, but you have my thanks.

Comment: Could you guys please help me out? im trying it but no luck